# insert list in a column with the pdfptable itext with data from a HashMap

Tags: java, itext, pdfptable

This model next provides the data of the inserted column in the table row. researched several examples in http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php but neither specifies how it should be done whens the data comes from a dataset and are converted to a HashMap:

```
PdfPTable tabela = new PdfPTable(columnNumber);
PdfPCell celula;    

    for (Entry<String, List<String>> item : matriz.entrySet()) {    
            for (String linha : item.getValue()) {
                 celula = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(linha, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD)));
                 tabela.addCell(celula);   
                dadosColuna.add(linha);
            }  
}
```

I'm trying the following example, where the list data is inserted into the cell. however, it would be interesting that each was given in a separate cell.

Then I tried the following:

```
// Imprimir linhas para cada chave/Coluna do Map
        for (Entry<String, List<String>> item : matriz.entrySet()) {    
            for (String linha : item.getValue()) {
                // celula = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(linha, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD)));
                // tabela.addCell(celula);   
                dadosColuna.add(linha);
            }  

            // Envolve esta linha em uma frase     
            Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
            for(int i = 0; i < dadosColuna.size(); i++)
                phrase.add(dadosColuna.get(i).toString());

            // phrase.add(dadosColuna.toString());

            PdfPCell phraseCell = new PdfPCell();

                phraseCell.addElement(phrase);  

            // Adiciona a celula a tabela   
            PdfPTable phraseTable = new PdfPTable(numeroColunas);
            phraseTable.setSpacingBefore(5);
            phraseTable.addCell(phraseCell);

            // Aplica a frase em uma outra tabela
            Phrase phraseTableWrapper = new Phrase();
            phraseTableWrapper.add(phraseTable);

        }
```

There are bugs in the line: phraseTable.addCell (phraseCell);

even if unsuccessful, list the HashMap brings in each iteration would be exposed in a cell only. I would like to enter each item in a corresponding cell your spine. Example: the current issue is:

```
heading 1, heading 2, heading 3 = OK!
given column 1, column data 1, as column 1, column 2 data given column 2, ...
```

I'm trying to apply this solution to the problem:
http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/ListInCell

Comment: the solution would be the possibility of tabela.addCell (cell); scroll vertically instead of horizontally. I have not found a method / itext attribute that premitisse this type of operation

Comment: You say you are looking at the [ListInCell](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/ListInCell) example, but I don't see you using `com.itextpdf.text.List` anywhere, so please take another look at that example.

Comment: Yes, I checked this example. But I just change the Dataset for this purpose. Thank you!

Comment: I wonder how do I break the table into two, as there are lots of columns. as did the separate rendering for columns and contents of the table (lines) I wonder if there is a method of breaking the table if you have a very large number of columns.